Academic papers on multi-currency accounting
Hello Economics Stackexchange. I'm currently writing my thesis titled "Multi-currency account management and translation exposure in MNCs: Applications in SAP", which as the title may suggest, extensively investigates multi-currency accounts for its functional use in SAP. However, I'm struggling to find any articles relating to multi-currency accounting, which comes as a surprise to me as its extensively used in multi-national industries all the time. I could only find the following:
https://www.emerald.com/insight/content/doi/10.1108/02686900010339364/full/html
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0020706397900327
Perhaps I'm searching using the wrong keywords. I would be really grateful if anyone could give me pointers or suggest some further articles (other than the ones I mentioned above) regarding multi-currency accounting.
